Pull data from multiple workbooks based on a dynamic list
I wrote this rudimentary vba code to pull data from multiple workbooks.
Sub AllocationPull()
Dim wkb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wkb2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wkb3 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wkb4 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wkb5 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wkb6 As Excel.Workbook

Dim wks1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wks2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wks3 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wks4 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wks5 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wks6 As Excel.Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wkb2 = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Sheet5.Range("C3").Value)
Set wkb3 = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Sheet5.Range("C4").Value)
Set wkb4 = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Sheet5.Range("C5").Value)
Set wkb5 = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Sheet5.Range("C6").Value)

Set wks1 = wkb1.Worksheets("Backend2")
Set wks2 = wkb2.Worksheets(Sheet5.Range("S3").Value)
Set wks3 = wkb3.Worksheets(Sheet5.Range("S4").Value)
Set wks4 = wkb4.Worksheets(Sheet5.Range("S5").Value)
Set wks5 = wkb5.Worksheets(Sheet5.Range("S6").Value)

With wks2
.Range("A1:B30").Copy Destination:=wks1.Range("A2")
End With
wkb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

With wks3
.Range("A1:B30").Copy Destination:=wks1.Range("C2")
End With
wkb3.Close SaveChanges:=False

With wks4
.Range("A1:B30").Copy Destination:=wks1.Range("E2")
End With
wkb4.Close SaveChanges:=False

With wks5
.Range("A1:B30").Copy Destination:=wks1.Range("G2")
End With
wkb5.Close SaveChanges:=False



Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

It is opening spreadsheets based on concatenate formulas in sheet 5 range C3:C20 including the file path & the name of the sheet I want to pull data from. This range is Dynamic so more often than not, the majority of the cells are blank--which as you can imagine stops my code from working. Is there a way to alter the code so it loops through range C3:C20 and only pulls data if the cell is not blank? I've done something similar in the past like
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook

For i = lastrow to 2 Step -1

but it's been years now so I'm not sure how to do these looping codes anymore.
Thanks!

Pull Data From Multiple Workbooks Based On a Dynamic List
Sub PullAllocations()

    ' Destination
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Backend2")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range("A2")
    Dim dColumnOffset As Long: dColumnOffset = dws.Range("A1:B30").Columns.Count
    
    ' Lookup
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = Sheet5 ' also in 'ThisWorkbook' (code name)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range("C3:C20")
    Dim lcell As Range: Set lcell = lrg.Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If lcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Set lrg = lrg.Resize(lcell.Row - lrg.Row + 1)
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range
    Dim sFilePath As String, sSheetName As String
    
    For Each lcell In lrg.Cells
        ' Retrieve the file and sheet names.
        sFilePath = CStr(lcell.Value)
        sSheetName = CStr(lcell.EntireRow.Columns("S").Value)
        If Len(sFilePath) > 0 And Len(sSheetName) > 0 Then ' both not blank
            ' Open, copy & close.
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
            Set sws = swb.Sheets(sSheetName)
            Set srg = sws.Range("A1:B30")
            srg.Copy Destination:=dcell
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        ' To copy consecutively (adjacent to each other) no matter
        ' the lookup cell, move this line right above the 'End If' line.
        Set dcell = dcell.Offset(, dColumnOffset) ' next destination cell
    Next lcell
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Allocations pulled.", vbInformation

End Sub

Edit

To cover for non-existing sheets, use:
 If Len(sFilePath) > 0 And Len(sSheetName) > 0 Then ' not blank
     ' Open, copy & close.
     Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
     Set sws = Nothing
     On Error Resume Next
         Set sws = swb.Sheets(sSheetName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     If sws Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "The sheet """ & sSheetName _
             & """ doesn't exist in workbook """ & swb.Name & """!", _
             vbExclamation
     Else
         Set srg = sws.Range("A1:B30")
         srg.Copy Destination:=dcell
     End If
     swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
 End If




Hey there! The code has been working for the most part but I am now getting a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range error which opens up the debugger to the line Set sws = swb.Sheets(sSheetName) I tried to figure out what the issue is myself but cant seem to get it to wor. Do you have any ideas of what I could do? Thanks!!!

The sheet doesn't exist. When the error occurs, press Debug and hover over the sSheetName variable to see what it holds. Replace the value in column S with an existing sheet name.

Ah I see. I will try that thank you! Do you how I could add a message box saying that the sheet doesn't exist instead of showing the run-time error?

I see your edit thanks for that! So I figured out what the exact issue was since I was getting that error and the workbook it was trying to pull from was certainly there correctly. The issue is with long sheet names since excel sheet names have a 31 character limit. Is there a way to remove the sheet name code? each file path leads to a CSV workbook which only has 1 sheet so I think the sheetname code may be redundant here.

In my initially posted code, Instead of Set sws = swb.Sheets(sSheetName) use Set sws = swb.Sheets(1) and remove the remaining 'traces' of sSheetName. Also, there is no need for the additional code.

I ended up fixing it just removed anything that had to do with sws and sSheetName and it works flawlessly for my setup. Should have been more descriptive sorry about that. Anyways thanks so much for the help!!
